How to parse a schedule format to four columns of data in excel

I am trying to parse this table to 4 columns shown on the right side. Is there a way to automatically do this counting consecutive client blocks while also skipping lunch blocks and finally making sure to count multiple blocks if a trainer works with a client twice in the same day.
I think that it has to be some combination of indexing and if statements, not sure how to have this made in a clean row by row format

Can you elaborate a bit more? Is it supposed to be for all trainers? Should it be a dropdown in which you can select the trainer? How about the clients?

It should be for all client session blocks visible on the schedule, which should also include all trainers. I essentially want a list of every client block with start times and end times from the schedule and the client name and trainer name

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This isn't a complete answer, if I find more time I'll try and get it better, but it's a start:
Setup
Make some named ranges: Time, NameA, NameB, NameC, ...
I started my table in A1 with Trainer, so for me Time is A3:A19, NameA is B3:B19 and so on.
Formula and explantation
In H2 you manually type the name of the trainer, NOTE! this has to be the exact same as you did with the named ranges;
In I2 I used this formula: =XLOOKUP(1,(INDIRECT(H2)<>"Lunch")*(INDIRECT(H2)<>0),INDIRECT(H2),"")
In J2 I then used =XLOOKUP(I2,INDIRECT(H2),Time,"")
In K2 I then used =XLOOKUP(I2,INDIRECT(H2),Time,"",,-1)
So let's explain so far:
I2 will search for a value of 1 in the 'temporary' arrays following the statement:
(INDIRECT(H2)<>"Lunch")*(INDIRECT(H2)<>0) are these temporary arrays, they basically replace your array with 0 or 1, depending on their logical return:
(INDIRECT(H2)<>"Lunch") returns 1 for all cells that are not lunch;
(INDIRECT(H2)<>0) returns 1 for all cells that or not '0';
Multiplying the results (with *) is basically using an AND operator;
So the whole thing just looks for the first filled cell, that is not 'Lunch';
J2 and K2 will look in the Time array, based on the position of whatever I2 returns (like INDEX/MATCH, if you're familiar with that), only difference between those two, K2 starts it's search from the bottom.

Now in I3 we want to make sure that you don't find the already searched value, so we need to add that in, it looks like this:
=IF(H2=H3,XLOOKUP(1,(INDIRECT(H3)<>"Lunch")*(INDIRECT(H3)<>0)*(INDIRECT(H3)<>I2),INDIRECT(H3),""),XLOOKUP(1,(INDIRECT(H3)<>"Lunch")*(INDIRECT(H3)<>0),INDIRECT(H3),"")
So what's going on?
You first check if H2 and H3 are the same (same trainer), if that's the case, it adds an extra bit (INDIRECT(H3)<>I2), this part will add in a different search from the first value.
The second part of the IF formula just does the same as before.
For the start and finish time it'll do the same.

Side notes
As stated before, this isn't the complete answer (yet); there will be a few errors produced:
Like NameE and NameD won't give you the full answer yet (because they have the same client twice in one day).
There's probably a way to wrap this thing in a LET function, to compact it a bit; but I hope this will get you started.
Here is what it looks like for me (so far):



This is awesome, thank you so much! I never would of thought of using an Xlookup!

@mribs glad I could help, there might be a better solution though; is the list of clients finite and constant? If it's a constant list of just a few (say 5 max, always the same) I think I can com up with a better solution.
